# Liferay CheckBox/Radio Styling

Tags: html, css, checkbox, radio-button, liferay

Hello I'm trying to style a Liferay Checkbox, I can't edit the HTML so I have to work straight on the CSS but I can't style it properly, in particular I found a strange behaviour on :checked selector.

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label for="_com_liferay_dynamic_data_lists_form_web_portlet_DDLFormPortlet_INSTANCE_qaCfYGoELD8F_ddm$$CheckBoxTest$ViVemTVR$0$$de_DE">
        <input id="_com_liferay_dynamic_data_lists_form_web_portlet_DDLFormPortlet_INSTANCE_qaCfYGoELD8F_ddm$$CheckBoxTest$ViVemTVR$0$$de_DE" name="_com_liferay_dynamic_data_lists_form_web_portlet_DDLFormPortlet_INSTANCE_qaCfYGoELD8F_ddm$$CheckBoxTest$ViVemTVR$0$$de_DE" type="checkbox" value="true"> CheckBox Test
            <span class="icon-asterisk text-warning"></span>
    </label>
</div>
```

And this is my CSS:

```
.checkbox input[type=checkbox] {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.checkbox {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #C6C6C6;
}

.checkbox:checked {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #C6C6C6;
}
```

Is there any work-around to handle this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-a-checkbox-using-css

Comment: I already checked that topic and I think it's not strictly related to this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this css will solve your problem

```
 .checkbox span {
     font-size: 19px;
     color: #898787;
     position: relative;
     cursor: pointer;
     padding-left: 30px;
     line-height: 33px;
     -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
     user-select: none;
}
.checkbox span:before {
     content: "";
     background-color: #FFFFFF;
      border-radius: 3px;
      border: 1px solid #C6C6C6;
     display: inline-block;
     position: absolute;
     width: 34px;
     height: 32px;
     left: 0;
     margin-left: -16px;
     overflow: hidden;
}
 .checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked + span:before {
     background: blue;
     width: 34px;
     height: 32px;
}
.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]{
     width: 0;
 }
```

Comment: Anuresh thanks so much, it works quite smoothly I was getting crazy :D

Comment: How I Could draw the "tick" into the checkbox?

Comment: Instead of background color u have to call background IMG of small tick